# TIMESTAMP vs TIMESTAMPTZ correct value when taking time difference

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

For the query:

```
SELECT '2018-03-01'::TIMESTAMP - '2018-09-01'::TIMESTAMP, 
       '2018-03-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ - '2018-09-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

the values `-184 days` for `TIMESTAMP` and `-183 days -23:00:00` for `TIMESTAMPTZ` is returned.

To me, `-184 days` "seems" correct but I was always told to use `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Timestamptz is actually timestamp with time zone data type which also takes care of timezones. It specifies the timezone at the end of the value like so: `+01`. See it for yourself `select current_date::timestamptz`. The choice of data type is really case specific.

Comment: @KamilG. But if `TIMESTAMPTZ` applies the same timezone data to each value, shouldn't the difference be the same?

Comment: The result `-183 days -23:00:00` is correct. Please investigate this: `select '2018-03-01'::timestamptz , '2018-09-01'::timestamptz;` There is a timezone difference of 1 hour probably due to daylight savings. This isn't the case when substracting `timestamp` type because it doesn't look at time differences spanned across zones and calendar.

Comment: @KamilG. ahhh daylight savings comes into play. Gotcha. If you post answer I can accept it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer posted as complement to comment discussion under OP's question.

---

Data type `timestamptz` is actually timestamp with time zone, while `timestamp` is timestamp without time zone.

The result that you get from substracting these specific dates like below is correct with 1 hour difference

```
SELECT '2018-03-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ - '2018-09-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

this is because `2018-03-01::timestamptz` has `+01` whereas `2018-09-01` has `+02`.

See it for yourself with this query

```
SELECT '2018-03-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2018-09-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ
```

1 hour difference **most likely** comes from daylight savings and changing timezone over time.

---

In general I would always choose to include time zones within my system to properly handle time differences across the world and avoid issues that may arise from not having this. Client and server may have different timezones which can lead to problems.

Comment: timestamptz isn't quite what most people seem to think it is.
It doesn't contain any Timezone-data, it however does store data in UTC and does the conversion "automagically" to the user depending on settings on the db-instance, the db itself or the current connection.

Comment: @flatrick I keep running into this explanation, and it makes good sense. But if it is so, then the Postgres documentation [1] is at best misleading, and at worst just wrong: Postgres doesn't "assume my local timezone" when dealing with naive timestamps, instead the timezone doesn't even enter the picture. Or else I am completely confused, so maybe you can help :) ... [1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

Comment: @q.undertow this is what the docs say on the page you've linked:

"For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time/../). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone."

The rest of what I mentioned is explained in the paragraphs after that section

Comment: @flatrick what I continue to find confusing about this matter, and that includes the relevant part of the doc, is the timestamp type *without* tz. The doc keeps dragging the local timezone into it, when it seems to me that *any* timezone consideration is irrelevant for this type.